# Hand over variable from a function inside node.js + twit package

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, twitter

I am using the package `twit`insite a `node.js` app to get some JSON data from Twitter.

I tried for hours to manage how I can hand over a variable from inside a function to the outside.

```
var tweets;
T.get('followers/ids', { screen_name: 'tolga_tezel' },  function (err, data, response) {
  tweets = data;
})
console.log(tweets); // -> undefiend

//data is the JSON I get from the Twitter Server. Console.log(data) shows it.
```

I know its because of the asynchronous thing, but I dont know how to manage this.

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Put your console.log inside your callback function.
If you want to process further, please put that code inside your callback function.
There are other ways also to work with Asynchronous nature of javascript.
You can use async.js library, which is very easy to use.

Comment: May you give me an example? :/

Comment: Async.js waterfall can help you here.
https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall

Comment: var tweets; T.get('followers/ids', { screen_name: 'tolga_tezel' }, function (err, data, response) { tweets = data;
console.log(tweets);
//Put your code here which is accessing tweets variable
 })

Comment: But I want to access the variable outside of the function and not inside of it.

Comment: In any case, You will have to wait until your function fetches the data.
You can do it with either callback or promises. But this is the way Async works.
If you want to access it outside of this block, then you can use promise based structure, in which inside 'then' method you can write the further code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to tackle your issue is to use Promises with Twit's promised package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/promised-twit)

In your code it would look something like this:

```
var Twit = require('promised-twit');

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key: '...',
  consumer_secret: '...',
  access_token: '...',
  access_token_secret: '...'
})

T.getFollowersIds({ screen_name: 'tolga_tezel' })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
})
```

Of course first install the package by running `npm install --save promised-twit`

The reason your current code doesn't return anything when you log it out because console.log runs before the twitter API returns any response from T.get()

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
What worked for me was (and maybe anyone searching for this):

```
var tweets = T.get('followers/ids', { screen_name: 'tolga_tezel' })
```

Calling `, function. (x,z)` somehow swallows data - idk what really happens there.

However, If you want to call error handlers or other functions
use `.catch()` and `.then()` instead
e.g.

```
T.get('followers/ids', { screen_name: 'tolga_tezel' }).then((response) => console.log(response.data)
```